# ForeignKey field with another ForeignKey in FormWizard with MultiValueField

Tags: python, django, django-formwizard, django-forms

I have a model with a ForeignKey to another model that also has a ForeignKey. I am rendering it with a django form wizard (trying to support as old a django version as possible) which is not *inlineformset friendly*. I want the user to put in both models and extra information in the form wizard and translate that into the correct pk value (that way the extra information can be dependend on a combination) I'm wondering about the best way to approach this.

To further clarify with code. I have three models:

```
class Subject(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(...)
   extra_info = models.CharField(...)

class Topic(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(...)
   extra_info = models.CharField(...)
   subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject)

class AwesomeThing(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(...)
   topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic)
```

Now, I want to present the *topic* field of *AwesomThing* to the user in my form wizard as four fields:

- Subject
- Subject extra information
- Topic
- Topic extra information

I'm using a *MultiValueField* with *MultiWidget* to accomplish this but I am unsure about the best way to keep the value and transfer it between the steps in the form wizard. I'm able to do this but I'm afraid that my method hits the database too frequently. Here's how I currently do this:

```
class SubjectTopicField(MultiValueField):
  widget = SubjectTopicInput # Multiwidget to present four input fields
  hidden_widget = HiddenInput

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    fields = (
      CharField(label='Subject'),
      CharField(label='Subject extra information'),
      CharField(label='Topics'),
      CharField(label='Topic extra information'),
        )

    super(SubjectTopicField, self).__init__(fields, *args, **kwargs)

  def compress(self, data_list):
    # If all four fields are present ...
    if data_list and len(data_list) == 4:
      # ... call and return the topic 'pk' value from a custom method that 
      # creates and/or gets the topic based on the subject and topic info
      return get_or_create_topic(data_list[0], data_list[1], # Subject
                                 data_list[2], data_list[3]) # Topic

    return None
```

My get_or_create_topic method basically just looks up whether this combination of subject and topic exists and if so returns it and if not creates it. The problem is that this means it has to hit the database in every step. I see that the hidden field presentation of this field just holds the list of values (the data_list) instead of the pk value of the topic. That's not optimal in my opinion. Is there a better way to do this? I might just be to focused on getting this to work with *MultiValueField* that I don't see the proper way to do this.

Comment: I figured this out. Since I can't self-answer my post because of reputation I'll wait for a few hours before I'll post the answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out I think. The answer was to use a *MultiWidget* subclass but not to subclass a MultiValueField. I just point my topics field to my SubjectTopicInput which inherits *MultiWidget* and then in addition to decompress I subclass value_from_datadict to return the pk (I know I can make it prettier but this is just what I did to get it working):

```
def value_from_datadict(self, data, files, name):
  # Is there just a single value available which we can return?
  single_value = data.get(name, None)
  if single_value: return single_value

  # No single value, let's try to find our topic (or create it)
  super_value = super(SubjectTopicInput, self).value_from_datadict(data, files, name)
  tc = get_or_create_topic(super_value[0], super_value[1],
                           super_value[2], super_value[3])

  if tc: return tc.pk 

  return None
```

Real easy when you stop digging and question whether the hole is really necessary.